# How to save windows screenshot directly to S3 bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to take screenshot of my windows application every 10 seconds and want it to save directly to S3 bucket.

Here is my code

```
        //execute every 10 seconds//
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                String filename = "ScreenCapture-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-hhmmss") +.png";
                Opacity = .0;
                g.CopyFromScreen((int)screenLeft, (int)screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                new MemoryStream(m.GetBuffer());
                Opacity = 1;

                //converting MemoryStream M to String // 
                byte[] byteImage = m.ToArray();
                var SigBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage); // Get Base64
            }
        }
        IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
        request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3
        request.FilePath = SigBase64; //local file name
        utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer
```

after running the code I am not getting any error message. but also it is not saving screenshot to S3 bucket either.

Comment: `new MemoryStream(m.GetBuffer());` - what is the purpose of this line? It doesn't achieve anything because you don't store the result.

Comment: Why not use `utility.Upload(fileName, bucketName, fileNameInS3)`?  [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MTransferUtilityUploadStringStringString.html)

Comment: Or use `utility.Upload(fileStram, bucketName, fileNameInS3)` [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MTransferUtilityUploadStreamStringString.html)